# Deleting Selected Part of Access Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-delete

I am trying to select a certain part of my access 2010 database to delete. Anything in my database older than 7 days. I have to code to compact the database I just don't know where to start for deleting a selected part of the database. Here is what I have so far:

```
'Compacting database

Dim DateA As Date = Date.Now
Dim DateB As String
'Subtracting the seven days from the current date.
DateB = Format(DateA.AddDays(-7.0), "MM/dd/yy")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'part of my Access 2010 database to delete'? As in, are you talking about records in all tables that are over seven days old, records in specific tables that are over seven days old, etc?

Comment: All record inside the databse (all tables) that are older than 7 days. I want to be able to locate them and delete them. Then I will compact the database (I already have the code for the databse).

Comment: If you have a field (i.e. CreationDate) that identify when a record is inserted then you can simply execute a DELETE.

Comment: Or would it be possible to just compact any data that is younger than seven days then just delete that database? What way would be more efficient? @kingalligator

Comment: I do have that field "ProdDate" but I am a newbie at this databse stuff, what is Delete a member of? @tezzo

Comment: This is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177896%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Okay, that looks pretty straight forward. Thank you very much for your time. @tezzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust this query as needed in an Access session:

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE ProdDate < DateAdd("d", -7, Date())
```

Since both the `Date()` and `DateAdd()` functions are recognized by the db engine, you can execute that `DELETE` statement from an OleDb connection to the Access db.

If the database contains multiple tables which must be thinned out, substitute each table name for *"YourTable"* and execute each of those modified statements.